# How to get a json object from servlet(.slt) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to load the contents of my web page's menu-bar by a URL. (This URL results in downloading a file with .slt file extension)

URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgoZYVaFm3ecFRGYThjcE85OUU/edit?usp=sharing

The "content.slt" file contains

```
{
"list": [
    {
        "productName": "bulb",
        "Code": "130",
        "levelNumber": 2,
        "itemId": 0
},

{
        "productName": "switch",
        "Code": "131",
        "levelNumber": 6,
        "itemId": 0
},

{
        "productName": "fan",
        "Code": "132",
        "levelNumber": 3,
        "itemId": 0
}


 ]
}
```

And I have used my java script like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {'

$.getJSON("https://www.******************", function(data) {

$.each(data.list, function (i, list) {

        var option = '<li class="list_1"><a href="#">' + list.productName + '</a>  </li>';

        $(option).appendTo('#product_details');
        });
});

});
```

Here i want to Load the productnames to my menu-bar directly from the URL.

with this above approach i am not getting the productName inside my menu-bar.

Comment: do you got json data from data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Json object data field is wrong. First object productName declare but second object declare Name only that is the issue. you will change it will work fine.
[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6AXm/1/)

```
var data = {
"list": [
{
    "productName": "bulb",
    "Code": "130",
    "levelNumber": 2,
    "itemId": 0
},

{
    "productName": "switch",
    "Code": "131",
    "levelNumber": 6,
    "itemId": 0
},

{
    "productName": "fan",
    "Code": "132",
    "levelNumber": 3,
    "itemId": 0
}


]
};
```

Comment: <pre>

I cant change my JSON object because it is coming from the URL, and my updated my script file with this 

$(document).ready(function () { 

 var data = "https://www.*************"; 
 $.each(data.list, function (i, list) {  
 console.log(list.productName); 
 var option = '<li><a href="#">' + list.productName + '</a></li>';
 $(option).appendTo('#product_details'); 
  }); 
});

still no results
is this script correct?

</pre>

Comment: are you see the demo link, will write console data.list object, It's have data or not